# Rmetrics for R version 3.0.0

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me how can I do to install Rmetric package on a 3.0.0 version?

```
 install.packages("Rmetrics", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/", dependencies = TRUE)
```

package 'Rmetrics' is not available (for R version 3.0.0)

I am using a putty console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rmetrics meta-package was retired many, many years ago.  Just install whichever components (say, fOptions) you want directly.